# Vue and data from REST API

Tags: vue.js

While playing around with vue.js I noticed some strange behavior while trying to display on a page data from an API, but here's the strange thing :

- using vue 2.0.0, i can see the "Title", but I have an error in dev console [see printscreen]
- using the latest vue version, i can't see the "Title" [and I have the same error in the printscreen]

Is it normal, or?

Source code :

```
  template:
    '<div>'+
      'Form with id = {{id}}'+
      '<br/>'+
      'has title = {{item.details.Title}}'+
    '</div>',
  data: function(){
    return {
      id: '',
      item: {}
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.get()
  },  
  methods: {
    get: function() {
      var self = this
      id = window.location.hash
      id = id.replace('#/whatever/','')
      axiosInstance.get('/thebackendresource/'+id) // <--- make http calls etc
        .then(function (response) {
          self.id = id
          self.item = response.data
          console.log(self.item)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

[image: This is the case when vue 2.0.0 is used]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error, because when you are fetching data from `axiosinstance`, that time `item.details` is null, and when it tries to render it throws this error.

Once the api call is completed, it updates the the DOM and in turn re-renders the DOM, so you can see `item.details.Title` rendered.

You need to add a null check to prevent this error, which can be easily done using [v-if](https://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html), like follwoing:

```
template:
'<div>'+
  'Form with id = {{id}}'+
  '<br/>'+
  '<span v-if="item.details"> has title = {{item.details.Title}}'+
  '</span>' +
'</div>',
```

Comment: I was hoping I could tweak this behavior from the component lifecycle, it's working